# Maven build cannot find symbol when accessing project lombok annotated methods,

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I'm using project lombok for the first time and I have problems compiling the project via maven when I run the build I receive errors where methods annotated with project lombok annotations are called.

This is the annotated parameter:

```
    private @Getter @Setter String paymentNonce = null;
```

and in this line for example the maven breaks the build:

```
if (!StringUtilities.isNullOrEmpty(getPaymentNonce())) {
```

this is my maven dependency

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.4</version> 
</dependency>
```

the maven error:

```
[INFO] Compiling 158 source files to C:\java\repos\luna\cloudflow\cloudflow-ejb\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \java\repos\luna\cloudflow\cloudflow-ejb\src\main\java\si\arctur\controller\PaymentProcessor.java:[94,38] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \java\repos\luna\cloudflow\cloudflow-ejb\src\main\java\si\arctur\controller\PaymentProcessor.java:[97,106] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \java\repos\luna\cloudflow\cloudflow-ejb\src\main\java\si\arctur\controller\PaymentProcessor.java:[142,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \java\repos\luna\cloudflow\cloudflow-ejb\src\main\java\si\arctur\controller\ShoppingCart.java:[27,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \java\repos\luna\cloudflow\cloudflow-ejb\src\main\java\si\arctur\controller\ShoppingCart.java:[32,75] error: cannot find symbol
.....
```

I'm using java 8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have downgraded the lombok to 1.14.8 this version works with maven build, I havent found why the 1.16 verson is not working :(

Comment: Experienced the same with maven 3.0.5, Netbeans 8.0.2, java 1.8.0_72-internal; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.72-b05 and downgrading to 1.14.8 made maven compile correctly. I've managed to compile a few time correctly with 1.16 but after a while it started to throw `error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: Just see my answer, and it will be fixed in lombok's next version.

Comment: This solved my issue! In my case Getters and Setters were not generated in Android Studio.

Answer (score 37):

Had the same problem using maven-compiler-plugin v.2.3.2
After updating the version up to 3.5 problem disappeared

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This solution is still valid with `maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1`.

Comment: I've tried version `maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1` and `maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0` but only `maven-compiler-plugin:3.5` would work with Lombok for me

Answer (score 17):

I was actually able to solve this by following an answer posted here :

[MapStruct and Lombok not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369)

Basically I had to add `lombok` to the `maven-compiler-plugin` `<annotationProcessorPaths>`

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Lombok related static methods (mainly @Builder) with static imports, you might experience similar issues (even in other parts of your code!).

There is an open issue about it: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/979

The current workaround is to simply not use static imports, e.g. change

```
import static my.org.Foo.FooBuilder
 ...
FooBuilder builder = Foo.builder();
```

to:

```
Foo.FooBuilder builder = Foo.builder(); // note >>Foo.<<FooBuilder; without static import
```

Comment: +1 This solved my problem. There is another workaround mentioned in the comments that I use now: "A work around is to create a static method that returns the builder in the class and use that one instead of the lombok generated one."

Comment: Experienced this with lombok v1.18.24, so static import of @Builder's issue is still relevant

Answer (score 8):

For other users using JDK9 and above you should add annotationProcessorPaths to maven compiler plugin

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.16</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Comment: I am using it with spring-boot, hibernate and vaadin, and this was the solution.
lombok is currently in 1.18.30 and still a reliable tool!

Answer (score 6):

My solution was to prefix the annotation with lombok package name.

```
@lombok.Builder
@lombok.experimental.Accessors(prefix = "m", chain = true)
```

rather than

```
@Builder
@Accessors(prefix = "m", chain = true)
```

Comment: In my case this solution worked for lombok annotations on nested classes.

Answer (score 3):

In short, upgrade `maven-compiler-plugin` to up `2.4`, or downgrade `lombok` to below `1.14.*`.

<strike>It seems that `maven-compiler-plugin` below `2.4` doesn't support `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` with a name with `$`.</strike>

Update: You can configuration `maven-compiler-plugin` to `fork`, or update `plexus-compiler-javac` to `1.8.6`. (`maven-compiler-plugin` `2.3.2` requires `1.8.1`, and `2.4` requires `1.8.6`)

Since `1.16`, lombok uses `ShadowClassLoader`, which prevents the IDE promotion for lombok's internal class. However, it doesn't use the `ShadowClassLoader` if the classloader is `org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.IsolatedClassLoader`. (I don't known why lombok guys use hard code to solve other issue *may* related with `plexus-compiler-javac`.)

`maven-compiler-plugin` `2.4`, or rather,  `plexus-compiler-javac` `1.8.6`, doesn't use `org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.IsolatedClassLoader`, so it works again.

Comment: A [pull request to solve this](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/pull/1138) has been merged and will be in lombok 1.16.9+. A [preview jar is available](https://projectlombok.org/download-edge.html) so please give it a try and give feedback.

Answer (score 3):

In my case i have got this error because a compile error in other class but the lombok was suppressing the real problem.
I recommend you to take a look in your classes to find some error.
I hope it helps you

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are using lombok annotations in static classes in that case you will have to mention the full name of the class ie. instead of `@Data` to `@lombok.Data` . This has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you've specified `-proc:none` or explicitly specified annotation processors using `-processor <processorclass>` in your java compilation (javac)?

Comment: actually if I downgrade the logbook version to 1.14.8 it works, only the new version from 1.16 on does not work

Comment: it's nothing with proc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solved by upgrading JDK (was 1.8.0_66, now 1.8.0_92)

Comment: It's not a issue related to jdk.

Comment: I see mentions to specific JDK versions on [lombok's changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog.html).
If someone knows why this specific issue can't be related to jdk, please share.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify  parameter for "lombok" module within dependencies.I faced the same issue and resolved this by this work around.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but for some reason it solves my problem.

I have two classes that use @Builder to generate a build method. But one is normal, the other one is abnormal. I have checked everything and it seems ok.
But when I run `mvn` to compile my project, the error is as follows:

> Can't not find the symbol
>   method builder()

```
import lombok.*;
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
class A {

}


import lombok.*;
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
class B {

}
```

Class A compiles correctly, but Class B reports the problem above.

I tried to replace the version of the Lombok JAR, but even though I set the version to latest, it's not ok.

So, I tried to import Lombok per class that I reference.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
class B {

}
```

It works! It seems a bug.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was, to **do not use** `import static` on lombok builder. Changing:

```
import static Foo.builder;

builder().id(1).build()
```

To:

```
Foo.builder().id(1).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed two config and it works.

1. someone set compiler args to `-proc:none` in compiler args:

   ```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven_compiler_version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
                <!--remove below compiler arg fixed my problem-->
                <compilerArg>-proc:none</compilerArg>
                <compilerArg>-parameters</compilerArg>
            </compilerArgs>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <source>${java_source_version}</source>
            <target>${java_target_version}</target>
            <encoding>${file_encoding}</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```
2. `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Java Compiler` > `Use compiler` is `Ajc`.

I use lombok 1.18.24 and java 8.

After remove `-proc:none` compiler argument and change compiler to `javac`, the project could be compiled in IDEA maven or in standalone maven.

Answer (score 0):

I designed the `<annotationProcessor>` in `maven-compiler-plugin`

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <annotationProcessors>
          <annotationProcessor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

*If none of the other (common) answers worked for you::*

*(this is an Rare case thats Unlikely to fit yours)*

1. Inside my project, I had a **java file** called `Comment.java`, 
   However, the inside of it is just **BLANK** 
   (or only comments, no `public class Comments`, no package declaration).
2. Run `mvn install` (using right click on the project in Eclipse)
3. -> Fail 
   eg::

   ```
   [ERROR] /G:/XXX/XXX/XXX/src/main/java/XXXX/SomeClassAA.java:[37,28] cannot find symbol
   symbol:   method add(SomeClassBB)
   ```
4. -> To solve this, dont use a Blank java class in your project.

---

- (Also, note, sometimes you need to run `mvn install` *twice*, 
  the 1st run fails for no reason, but 2nd run success. 
  Idk why (maybe doing mvn clean 1st time). & Probably not be your case.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I annotated @Nullable into Optional generic type.It seem not unsupported this "Target".

```
public record DTO(Optional<@Nullable Integer> userId){
}
```