# Cannot compile Lombok's extension method invocation in Lambda using Maven with Java8

Tags: java, maven, lambda, java-8, lombok

I have a problem with the following code:

```
public class A {
    public String someMethod() {
        return "some";
    }
}

public class AExtension {
    public static void extensionMethod(A a, String s) {
        System.out.println(a.someMethod() + s);
    }
}

@ExtensionMethod({ AExtension.class })
public class ExtensionMethodExample {

    public void test(List<String> someList) {
        A a = new A();
        someList.stream().forEach(x -> a.extensionMethod(x)); 
    }
}
```

And while compiling this code using Maven I get:

```
[ERROR] [...]ExtensionMethodExample.java:[12,49] cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method extensionMethod(java.lang.String)
    location: variable a of type [...].A
```

The error only occurs while compiling using Maven, while running in Eclipse everything seems to work properly.

Some of my config:

```
maven-compiler-plugin: 3.5.1
lombok: 1.16.10 (I also tried 1.16.2)
```

**Update:**
Invocation without Lambda expression works, of course.

Comment: should a.extensionMethod(x) call compile at all if the signature is extensionMethod(A a, String s)?

Comment: This is a lombok feature https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod.html.

Comment: Take a look at this thread, it may answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358689/maven-build-cannot-find-symbol-when-accessing-project-lombok-annotated-methods