# Lombok does not generate Methods

Tags: eclipse, lombok

I'm trying to use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) in a Maven project with Java 8, but Lombok doesn't generate any Getters and Setters when I apply the [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) Annotation. I tried to use Maven Compiler Plugin Version 3.5 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358689/maven-build-cannot-find-symbol-when-accessing-project-lombok-annotated-methods), but it didn't help. Does anybody have I clue, which versions I need to use?

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.14</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Have you checked to use most recent version 3.6.1 of [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) ?

Comment: It seems that methods are created, but not recognised by Eclipse IDE. I created a Unit Test, which runs just fine. The test uses getter and setter, created by Lombok. Is there a way, that Eclipse is aware of the generated methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios).

1. Download Lombok JAR from [here](https://projectlombok.org/download.html).
2. Doubleclick the JAR and install it in your Eclipse installation directory
3. Restart Eclipse and check whether you can find this text: Help > About Eclipse > "Lombok vX.XX.XX is installed. https://projectlombok.org/". It should be found somewhere in the about text.
4. Open `eclipse.ini` in your Eclipse installation directory and add following lines at the end. (if they do not already exist)

   ```
   -javaagent:lombok.jar
   -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
   ```