# MapStruct + Lombok together not compiling: unknown property in result type

Tags: java, maven, lombok, mapstruct, intellij-lombok-plugin

Tech Stack being used :

Java 8
MapStruct : 1.2.0.Final
Lombok: 1.16.18
IDE: IntelliJ - Lombok Plugin already installed

- Initially, I faced issues when I removed getters and setters and added `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotation, `mapstruct` is not able to find the property and says: `Unknown property "id" in result type com.vg.once.dto.OneDto. Did you mean "null"?`
- I came to know that Lombok 1.16.14 or newer along with MapStruct 1.2.0.Beta1 or newer are compatible and can work together, but my versions are newer then the desired still the issue is arising.
- One more solution that I have already tried is running Lombok's Delombok plugin, but still, the same issue is arising.

Below are the project files :

The Entity Object: **One.java**:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class One {

    private int id;
    private Integer version;
    private int projectId;
    private String title;
    private String code;
    private int sortOrder;

}
```

The DTO Object: **OneDTO.java** :

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class OneDto {

    private int id;
    private Integer version;
    private int projectId;
    private String title;
    private String code;
    private int sortOrder;

}
```

Mapper Class : **OneMapper.java**

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

import com.vg.once.dto.OneDto;
import com.vg.once.entity.One;

@Mapper
public interface OneMapper {

    @Mapping(target="id", source="one.id")
    OneDto createOne (One one);

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.vg</groupId>
  <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Mapstruct-test</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.16.18</org.projectlombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins> 
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.18.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>delombok</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                    <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/delombok</outputDirectory>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>       
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>
```

**Build Trace**:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mapstruct-test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- lombok-maven-plugin:1.16.18.1:delombok (default) @ mapstruct ---
[INFO] Delombok complete.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mapstruct ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ mapstruct ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /home/vivekgupta/Documents/workspaces/mapstruct-test/mapstruct/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/vivekgupta/Documents/workspaces/mapstruct-test/mapstruct/src/main/java/com/vg/once/mapper/OneMapper.java:[12,9] Unknown property "id" in result type com.vg.once.dto.OneDto. Did you mean "null"?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.637 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-06T19:23:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/235M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project mapstruct: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/vivekgupta/Documents/workspaces/mapstruct-test/mapstruct/src/main/java/com/vg/once/mapper/OneMapper.java:[12,9] Unknown property "id" in result type com.vg.once.dto.OneDto. Did you mean "null"?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

please share how can i get this working using both Lombok and MapStruct together?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is because Maven only uses the MapStruct processor and not the Lombok one. The `annotationProcessorPaths` tells maven which processors it should use.

The delombok does nothing as you are ending up with 2 files per class and I think that the maven compiler does not see them.

You have 2 options:

Option 1: Add the lombok dependency in the `annotationProcessorPaths`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.18.16 and above -->
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.0</version>
            </path>
            <!-- Mapstruct should follow the lombok path(s) -->
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Option 2:

Add the `mapstruct-processor` dependency to your dependencies and remove the `annotationProcessorPaths`. This way the maven compiler will pick up all the annotation processors that are in your dependencies.

I would advise in using Option 1, as with that you can be certain that you are not using some `MapStruct` transitive dependencies and internal classes in your code.

Edit:

To make sure that the IntelliJ annotation processing also works you will have to add the `mapstruct-processor` as a `provided` dependency due to [IDEA-150621](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150621). IntelliJ in the moment does not use the `annotationProcessorPaths` from Maven to configure the project correctly.

Edit 2:

Add information and comment about `lombok-mapstruct-binding` needed from Lombok 1.18.16.

Comment: I think "lombok" should come first then "mapstruct-processor"

Comment: The order should not make a difference. We were explicitly working on that with the Lombok team

Comment: I think this information definitively needs to be added to mapstructs [FAQ](http://mapstruct.org/faq/). Their example project is working without annotation processors defined in mavens build section, but I think they could mention it there (took me some time to find the solution here).

Comment: Here is a full example from MapStructs GitHub (Gradle and Maven): https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-lombok/

Comment: Confirmed the same behavior at IntelliJ 2020.2.3 a this time (dont forget "provided" in dependency)

Comment: Thank you for the comment about **lombok-mapstruct-binding** (https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Can-I-use-MapStruct-together-with-Project-Lombok). Available version: [0.2.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-mapstruct-binding/0.2.0).
Only one thing `<!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.8.16 and above -->` => `<!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.18.16 and above -->`

Comment: lombok-mapstruct-binding solved my issues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Option 1 solved this for me, but only when I placed the mapstruct path before lombok.

Comment: adding Lombok before Mapstruct processor worked for me aswell @DonSrinath

Comment: It seems the order is important. Adding Lombok before Mapstruct processor worked for me too.

Comment: Option 2 does not work for me with Lombok 1.18.18

Comment: For people who have tried changing the order of dependencies but it was not resolved, please try changing the version of lombok

Comment: For us, annotation processor path order mattered, otherwise mapstruct ignored the builder and tried to use a non-accessible all-args-constructor. For mapstruct `1.4.2.Final` and lombok `1.18.20` we had to use `mapstruct-processor` **at first**. the order of `lombok` and `lombok-mapstruct-binding` did not matter.

Comment: For option 1 when using gradle, use `annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0"` to resolve the issue.

Comment: the mapstruct (with lombok) documentation : https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_set_up

Comment: @DonSrinath yes, order matters. Tested versions of lombok and mapstruct are 1.18.22 and 1.3.0.Final, respectively

Comment: When declaring lombok first and then mapstruct, it's not possible to use @SuperBuilder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607342/mapstruct-seems-not-recognize-lomboks-superbuilder

Answer (score 40):

Just in case if somebody is looking for how to configure it using Gradle:

```
dependencies {

   // Lombok
   compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
   annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'

   // MapStruct
   compileOnly 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.2.0.Final'
   annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.2.0.Final'

}
```

Comment: This will no longer work without lombok-mapstruct-binding

Comment: @PiotrŻak how is that?

Comment: If you are using Lombok 1.18.16 or newer you also need to add lombok-mapstruct-binding in order to make Lombok and MapStruct work together. https://mapstruct.org/faq/

Answer (score 28):

After multiple attempts in my Spring Boot Maven project, the following finally worked:

Configuration of pom.xml:

1. The properties section:

```
    <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
            <version.lombok>1.18.18</version.lombok>
            <version.mapstruct>1.4.2.Final</version.mapstruct>
            <version.mapstruct-lombok>0.2.0</version.mapstruct-lombok>
        </properties>
```

2. The dependencies section:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${version.lombok}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct-lombok}</version>
        </dependency>
```

3. The build plugins section:

```
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>9</source>
                        <target>9</target>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>${version.lombok}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                                <version>${version.mapstruct-lombok}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Hope this helps, my mapper before did not map the field values, but now these are mapper between the source and the target + the nested list of elements in each is also being mapped along with field values.

Comment: Still actual in dec.2021, thank you

Answer (score 23):

For me solution was realy simple.

The order of the processors was important.

In my case mapstruct processor was defined before lombok processor. In case with bad order mapstruct does not generate mappings, just create instance of result class (i saw that in generated implementation).

My plugin configuration with right order:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>15</source>
        <target>15</target>
        <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And of course you need to add dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi, I got those paths in that order but It didn't help.

Comment: @denu, agree, I don't think the order matters, not a helpful answer

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issues. Turned out my MapStruct version was outdated!

I used MapStruct version 1.1.0.Final, but **for Lombok support at least 1.2.0.Final is required**.

Answer (score 6):

**If anyone is reading this when using the latest Lombok and Mapstruct library versions**:-

If you are using Lombok 1.18.16 or newer then you also need to add `lombok-mapstruct-binding` in order to make Lombok and MapStruct work together.

https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Can-I-use-MapStruct-together-with-Project-Lombok

Answer (score 6):

I feel a right way to declare versions in pom.xml is to refer to something like [this](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/3.1.2) for versions instead of manually specifying versions of everything. e.g. `maven-compiler-plugin.version`, `lombok.version` is already present there

properties block -

```xml
<properties>
  <java.version>17</java.version>
  <mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</mapstruct.version>
  <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
</properties>
```

dependencies block -

```xml
<dependencies>
  <!-- ... -->

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

build block -

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
  <!-- ... -->

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
          <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
          </path>

          <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
          </path>

          <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
          </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you. For me, it worked using just :

        `<path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
          </path>`

Answer (score 4):

For issues after upgrading Intellij to 2020.3 version, following solution worked for me.
Use lombok version: 1.18.16, lombok-mapstruct-binding: 0.2.0

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Change the order of the lombok and mapstruct plugin path in annotation processing section of plugins:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>

                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is how you are supposed to load multiple annotation processors in Gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final", "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final", "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20", "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still looking for this answer, I faced a similar issue with JOOQ + MapStruct Integration. The answer is the order of paths matters

- IntellijIdea 2020.2.3
- Java 8
- Spring Framework 2.4.0

My build snippet

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.8.16 and above -->
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

The mapstruct was just returning a null instance. Recently I upgraded the Intellij version to 2020.3, and spring boot 2.4.0, and landed into this situation.

When I changed the spring version to 2.3.o.RELEASE, I could see after compilation is that mapstruct was building the mappings properly.

Going through the post that mapstruct has recently updated.. but it will take time.. :) so, for now, I moved from maven to Gradle project and all working absolutely fine.. sounds weird but true...

I would be thankful if anyone would post what exactly the right issue and what's the solution.

Answer (score 2):

For people who uses build gradle, this is the .gradle file I successfully created

```
dependencies {

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:${gradleMapstructVersion}"

implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}"
annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"

}
```

The things is that, as said above, we have to use the `org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding` in order to use mapstruct with lombok

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a maven root module and submodules with dependency management, then you need to ensure that the order in your submodule configuration corresponds to the items that you've put in the root pom:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.18.16 and above -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Ensure the same order in the submodule!:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Not a good user experience for a library that is widely promoted, fix this for the sake of the Java community!

Answer (score 2):

No need for `lombok-mapstruct-binding`

Just put `lombok` before `mapstruct-processor`

```
ext {
    lombokVersion = '1.18.28'
    mapstructVersion = '1.5.5.Final'
}

dependencies {
    // Lombok - Important : Lombok before mapstruct
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"

    // Mapstruct
    compileOnly "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the order does play its role, also when using gradle. In my case it was failing as soon I was adding `subprojects { ... dependencyManagement{}}` to the parent `build.gradle` in a multimodule setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you have reached till here, that means none of the above solutions worked for you. Finally what worked for me was:

1. The following order of annotation processor in `pom.xml`

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
 ...
       <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </path>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </path>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </path>
 ...
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

2. The following setting of Annotation Processors in Intellij IDEA Preferences. Make sure your project is in the right profile. In my case the profile is `Annotation Profile for Alippo` and project is `alippo`. I really don't know how the configuration made the difference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, switching the order of the dependencies inside `build.gradle` so that `lombok` is first and `mapstruct` second was the only way to make it work.

I wasn't even aware that the order mattered in the dependencies list, but I've done nothing else and it's working perfectly now.

Throws compilation error because it cannot find any properties at all in the java classes:

```
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.3.Final'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

Works perfectly:

```
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.3.Final'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring-Boot the simplest configuration with exclude processing code from result jar:

`pom.xml`

```
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ....
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- exclude from jar-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Without `lombok-mapstruct-binding` it also works fine.
Maybe somebody comments, what for does it needed?

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to add the following dependencies:

```
implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final")
annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final")

compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0")
```

Format: Gradle(Kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>
                        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                    </compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gradle Kotlin dsl, try this in your build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
   // ...
   val kotlinVersion = "1.9.10"

   kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
   kotlin("kapt") version kotlinVersion
   // ...
}
// ...
dependencies {
  // ...
  kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor")
  kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
  implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final")
  compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16")
  annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16")
  annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0")
  // ...
}
// ...
kapt {
  keepJavacAnnotationProcessors = true
  // if needed, here is an example of mapStruct global config
  arguments {
    arg("mapstruct.defaultComponentModel", "spring")
  }
}
```

You would need to be sure that annotation processors has been enabled in your IDE and lombok plugins has been also installed

Answer (score 0):

So for recap you must get ride of those points:

1. Check the preprocessors orders, in some cases chenging the order , try to putting the mapstruct path to the last place.
2. Check if with mvn compile properly, in that case is an intellij IDE problem
3. Try to specify in the POM the latest version of Lombok and so on until you find a working version in intellij

Answer (score -1):

i have working mapstruct + lombok with following versions

1. java 17
2. mapstruct 1.3.1.Final
3. spring boot 2.7.6
4. lombok 1.18.26
5. lombok-mapstruct-binding 0.2.0
6. maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1

Map struct > 1.4 versions dosent work with latest lombok versions. So in updated versions i have to downgrade mapstruct to make it work

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
                        </path>

                        <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.18.16 and above -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.26</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```