# @Accessors(fluent = true) from lombok and mapstruct together

Tags: java-8, lombok, mapstruct

I have a downstream service whose beans I want to map to my beans. But there seems to be a problem with using mapstruct.

Pojo from the downstream service (whose definition i can't change)

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class PojoA {
   private String stringA;
   private int integer;
}
```

and I want to convert it to PojoB

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
public class PojoB {
    private String stringB;
    private int integer;
}
```

Mapper Interface

```
@Mapper
public interface PojoMapper {

    PojoMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PojoMapper.class);
    @Mapping(source = "stringA", target = "stringB")
    PojoB pojoAToPojoB(PojoA pojoA);
}
```

This fails as it fails to find getters as fluent remove the prefixes from the getters and,
I know mapstruct generates the implementation of the mapper interface and uses bean specifications (i.e get and set prefixes)

Is there a way to get past that?

Comment: You'd need to manually do specify the mappings

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Elaborate a little, please. By manually, do you mean, that I have to write a method to translate the object back and forth?

Comment: Actually just found out Mapstruct can handle your exact example, http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy

Comment: The doc says it can, but it can’t. I have the very same problem, and I’ve not been able to work around it. Needing help too.

Answer (score 9):

As specified in the comments this is possible by writing a custom `AccessorNamingStrategy` which would return the name of the method as a fluent accessor.

I have written a custom builder accessor (that can be applied in your case as well), you can find it [here](https://github.com/filiphr/mapstruct-builder-accessor).

On top of that there is an open PR [#1373](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1373) for MapStruct which adds support for builders and in the same go it adds support for fluent chained accessors.

Your custom strategy (as proposed in the PR) can look like:

```
public class FluentAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isSetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
        String methodName = method.getSimpleName().toString();

        return methodName.startsWith( "set" ) && methodName.length() > 3 || isBuilderSetter( method );
    }

    protected boolean isBuilderSetter(ExecutableElement method) {
        return method.getParameters().size() == 1 &&
            !JAVA_JAVAX_PACKAGE.matcher( method.getEnclosingElement().asType().toString() ).matches() &&
            method.getReturnType().toString().equals( method.getEnclosingElement().asType().toString() );
    }

    @Override
    public String getPropertyName(ExecutableElement getterOrSetterMethod) {
        String methodName = getterOrSetterMethod.getSimpleName().toString();
        if ( methodName.startsWith( "is" ) || methodName.startsWith( "get" ) || methodName.startsWith( "set" ) ) {
            return Introspector.decapitalize( methodName.substring( methodName.startsWith( "is" ) ? 2 : 3 ) );
        }
        else if ( isBuilderSetter( getterOrSetterMethod ) ) {
            return methodName;
        }
        return Introspector.decapitalize( methodName.substring( methodName.startsWith( "is" ) ? 2 : 3 ) );
    }
}
```

NB: This would work for fluent setters, you would need to do something extra to make it work for the fluent getters. Based on the `meethod.getEnclosingElement()`, which returns you the type, you would need to get the `Accessors` annotation check for the property and return the name of the method, otherwise you need to use the defaults.

Disclaimer: I am one of the members of the MapStruct team

Comment: I did not get time to implement this because I got stuck in another issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753526/nested-target-in-mapstruct-using-lombok-not-working-fluently) and now I am giving this all a second thought should I really go with mapstruct as it is giving me a hard time with Lombok, I will surely check this and mark as correct if this thing worked.

Comment: MapStruct works with Lombok, you need to check if your setup is correct. If you are using `annotationProcessorPaths` then you need to specify both MapStruct and Lombok in there. Make sure you are using the latest version of both frameworks and latest of the maven-compiler-plugin

Comment: Does this needs to be published in a separate project and imported as a lib? Or is there a possibility to extend mapstruct in the same project or one of the subprojects?

Comment: how to setup mapstruct with lombok can be found here https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#lombok there is also discussion how to setup mapstruct with lombok here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-lombok-together-not-compiling-unknown-property-in-result-type