# Mapstruct - Field required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I need to use Mapstruct and this error is comming up.

> *APPLICATION FAILED TO START Description: Field userMapper in com.mycomp.myappapi.service.UserService required a bean of type
> 'com.mycomp.myappapi.mapper.UserMapper' that could not be found. The
> injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>   Action: Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.mycomp.myappapi.mapper.UserMapper' in your configuration.*

Since there's this line in `myappapiApplication.java`, understand it should be able to find `UserMapper.java`. But for some reason it's not.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycomp.*"})
```

Also, it is not autogenerating the mapstruct implementation classes in `\target` folder.

```
package com.mycomp.myappapi;


@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.mycomp.myappapi.model"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycomp.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mycomp.myappapi.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class myappapiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(myappapiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package com.mycomp.myappapi.mapper;


@Mapper(componentModel = "Spring")
public interface UserMapper {   
    
    User UserRequestDTOtoUser(UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO);
    
    UserResponseDTO UserToUserResponseDTO(User user);
    
    
}
```

```
package com.mycomp.myappapi.service;

...

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;      
    
    public UserResponseDTO saveUser(UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO) {
        
        User user = userMapper.UserRequestDTOtoUser(userRequestDTO);
        
        ...
        
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        
        UserResponseDTO userResponseDTO = userMapper.UserToUserResponseDTO(savedUser);      
        
        return userResponseDTO;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mycomp.myappapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>myappapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myappapi</name>
    <description>aaa</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>3.8.1</version>-->
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>11</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>                        
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
        
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: how do you inject a `UserMapper` instance?

Comment: @Sharon Ben Asher I edited the question adding the ```@Service``` class to show that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `spring` instead of `Spring`. [The documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#configuration-options) does not have an upper case. Even better: add the config to your pom.xml, then you don't have to specify the `componentModel`for every mapper:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <!--<version>3.8.1</version>-->
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
        <target>11</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <!-- other annotation processors -->
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I tried both ways and neither of them worked. I don't think that is the problem as I have used uppercase @Mapper(componentModel = "Spring")  in the past with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

according to this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct#2-inject-spring-components-into-the-mapper

> Sometimes, we'll need to utilize other Spring components inside our
> mapping logic. In this case, we have to use an abstract class instead
> of an interface

try to change `UserMapper` into an abstract class.

Comment: I've tried that already. Then the error changes to this one: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for com.mycomp.myappapi.mapper.UserMapper   - and the MapStruct autogenerated classes are still not created in the \target folder.

Comment: according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710510/mapstruct-cannot-find-implementation
you should do `mvn clean install`

Comment: are you running the application in IDE? if so, you need to enable annotation processing in the IDE

Comment: maven clean install is the same as going to STS > right click project name in Package Explorer > Run As > maven clean, rigth? When I do that and run it again I get this error: "Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycomp.myappapi.myappapiApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycomp.myappapi.myappapiApplication" Then I go to STS > Project > Clean, run it again and it goes back to the same error of the original question.

Comment: yes, I'm running it in Spring Tool Suite IDE. Already had annotation processing configured by going to Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Annotation Processing > checked "Enable project Specific Settings", checked "Enable annotation processing", checked "Enable processing in editor"