# @MAPSTRUCT. No property named "packaging" exists in source parameter(s)

Tags: java, spring-boot, class, dto, mapstruct

I am writing an `MVC` `REST` application with `Spring Boot` and `Hibernate`. I decided to do `DTO` mapping using `MAPSTRUCT`. It seems that I did everything according to the guide, but an error is issued. What is the problem, I cannot understand. There is very little information on forums and on google.

P.S. At first I thought that the problem was in `Lombok`, so I removed `Lombok` and manually assigned `getters / setters`. Then the problem was not solved. I took both in the `Drink` class and in the `DrinkDTO` I prescribed `getters / setters`. It still didn't help.

Drink:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "drink", schema = "public")
public class Drink {

    public Drink() { // Constructor for Hibernate

    }


    // Fields
    //
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private float price;

    @Column(name = "about")
    private String about;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    // Relationships
    //
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "packaging_id")
    private Packaging packaging;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Countries countries;
}
```

DrinkDTO:

```java
public class DrinkDTO {

    // Fields
    //
    private String drinkName;

    private float drinkPrice;

    private String drinkAbout;

    private Packaging drinkPackaging;

    private Manufacturer drinkManufacturer;

    private Countries drinkCountries;


    // Getters and Setters
    //
    public String getDrinkName() {
        return drinkName;
    }

    public void setDrinkName(String drinkName) {
        this.drinkName = drinkName;
    }

    public float getDrinkPrice() {
        return drinkPrice;
    }

    public void setDrinkPrice(float drinkPrice) {
        this.drinkPrice = drinkPrice;
    }

    public String getDrinkAbout() {
        return drinkAbout;
    }

    public void setDrinkAbout(String drinkAbout) {
        this.drinkAbout = drinkAbout;
    }

    public Packaging getDrinkPackaging() {
        return drinkPackaging;
    }

    public void setDrinkPackaging(Packaging drinkPackaging) {
        this.drinkPackaging = drinkPackaging;
    }

    public Manufacturer getDrinkManufacturer() {
        return drinkManufacturer;
    }

    public void setDrinkManufacturer(Manufacturer drinkManufacturer) {
        this.drinkManufacturer = drinkManufacturer;
    }

    public Countries getDrinkCountries() {
        return drinkCountries;
    }

    public void setDrinkCountries(Countries drinkCountries) {
        this.drinkCountries = drinkCountries;
    }

    // toSTRING
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DrinkDTO{" +
                "drinkName='" + drinkName + '\'' +
                ", drinkPrice=" + drinkPrice +
                ", drinkAbout='" + drinkAbout + '\'' +
                ", drinkPackaging=" + drinkPackaging +
                ", drinkManufacturer=" + drinkManufacturer +
                ", drinkCountries=" + drinkCountries +
                '}';
    }
```

CustomerController:

```java
@GetMapping("/drinks")
    List<DrinkDTO> getAllDrinks(){
        return DrinkMapper.INSTANCE.drinksToDrinksDTO(customerService.getAllDrinks());
    }
```

BUILD.GRADLE

```java
// Mapstruct
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
```

DrinkMapper:

```java
@Mapper
public interface DrinkMapper {

    DrinkMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DrinkMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "drinkName")
    @Mapping(source = "price", target = "drinkPrice")
    @Mapping(source = "about", target = "drinkAbout")
    @Mapping(source = "packaging", target = "drinkPackaging")
    @Mapping(source = "manufacturer", target = "drinkManufacturer")
    @Mapping(source = "countries", target = "drinkCountries")
    DrinkDTO drinkToDrinkDTO(Drink drink);

    @Mapping(source = "drinkName", target = "name")
    @Mapping(source = "drinkPrice", target = "price")
    @Mapping(source = "drinkAbout", target = "about")
    @Mapping(source = "drinkPackaging", target = "packaging")
    @Mapping(source = "manufacturer", target = "drinkManufacturer")
    @Mapping(source = "countries", target = "drinkCountries")
    Drink drinkDTOtoDrink(DrinkDTO drinkDTO);

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "drinkName")
    @Mapping(source = "price", target = "drinkPrice")
    @Mapping(source = "about", target = "drinkAbout")
    @Mapping(source = "packaging", target = "drinkPackaging")
    @Mapping(source = "manufacturer", target = "drinkManufacturer")
    @Mapping(source = "countries", target = "drinkCountries")
    List<DrinkDTO> drinksToDrinksDTO(List<Drink> drinks);
}
```

ERRORS:
[image]

Comment: Did you use  mvn -clean install to generate the classes? Could you check that what does you have under target/generated-sources ?

Comment: Not. I do not use. How can I see this?

Comment: You don't need separate `@Mapping`s on method `List<DrinkDTO> drinksToDrinksDTO(List<Drink> drinks)` as mapping rules are implicitly inherited from `drinkToDrinkDTO` method

Comment: Also this link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you tried to map properties from `List<>` objects, but those don't exist. Mapstruct is smart enough to generate mappers between lists, provided it knows how to map the elements inside the list.

So you don't need to specify `@Mapping` annotations on the list-to-list mapping. Mapstruct will use the `drinkToDrinkDTO` mapping method automatically.

```
@Mapping(...)
DrinkDTO drinkToDrinkDTO(Drink drink);

List<DrinkDTO> drinksToDrinksDTO(List<Drink> drinks);
```

Answer (score 98):

For those, who have the same issue when using `mapstruct` + `lombok`:

I had the same issue. The reason was that I've been using `Lombok` plugin too.
There's **no need** to remove it, but you have to ensure that in `pom.xml` in `<annotationProcessorPaths>` Lombok tag is before the Mapstruct one.

Example (part of pom.xml file):

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId> <!-- IMPORTANT - LOMBOK BEFORE MAPSTRUCT -->
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: The ordering did not seem to do the trick for me, but adding this annotation processor as well did:
`<path>
<groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
<artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
<version>0.2.0</version>
</path>`

Comment: I had a problem with the warning from the original question being shown in Netbeans IDE although I am using the `lombok-mapstruct-binding`.

A similar issue appeared when using "Mapping Composition" from Mapstruct.
Both issues showed a problem in Netbeans' code editor, but were not stopping the project from being compiled and running without problems.

What solved these issues for me was ordering the `<annotationProcessorPaths>` like:
1. Lombok
2. Mapstruct-processor 
3. Lombok-mapstruct-binding

Comment: I had the same issue, the trick is working for me

Comment: Thanks for that one. Worked for me as well and save me some headache

Comment: After lots of searching, this finally helped. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It solved my same issue...

Comment: If you don't have them under annotationProcessorPaths, just make sure that lombok comes first as a dependency under dependencies, that did the trick for me.

Comment: The same is true using gradle and build.gradle: the lombok annotationProcessor config has to be before the mapstruct annotation processor.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to @Jakub Słowikowski answer, the same happens with gradle dependencies. The following order was causing the error:

```
dependencies {    
...
annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}")

annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")
...
}
```

hence I was forced to switch the order:

```
dependencies {    
...
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")
    
annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}")
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was wondering what was I doing wrong. This was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error did not stem from the declaration order of the annotationProcessors but from a missing Lombok annotation.

I had a mapping for `Customer` to `CustomerDto`, but the `Customer` was missing getters and setters.

```java
CustomerDto toCustomerDto(Customer customer);
```

With

```java
@Data
public class CustomerDto {
  ...
}
```

and

```java
public class Customer {
  ...
}
```

Adding `@Data` to the `Customer` class solved the issue for me.

Comment: The irony is, in case Customer is an entity, you shouldn't use `@Data`

Answer (score 0):

Try add a uses parameter in @Mapper annotation if you also have PackakingMapper, CoutriesMapper ... , like this:

```
@Mapper(uses = {PackagingMapper.class, CountriesMapper.class, ManufacturerMapper.class})
public interface DrinkMapper{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**just put lombok dependencie as first dependencie in your pom.xml file**

**then reload maven project**

you don't need to add mapstruct plugin, i just used **dependencies**

```
    <dependencies>
    **<dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>**
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Trust me**
**you can still use Lombok in your project even if you have excluded it in the Spring Boot Maven plugin configuration.
The excludes configuration in the plugin simply tells Maven to exclude the specified artifact from the plugin's classpath. In this case, the lombok artifact is being excluded from the Spring Boot Maven plugin's classpath, but it is not being excluded from your project's classpath.**

Answer (score 0):

For those, who have the same issue when using `mapstruct + lombok` 
**Adding lombok before mapstruct works as**
Both `lombok` & `Mapstruct` are based on `annotation-processor`, and mapstruct depends on getter & setter generated from lombok to generate the Mapper implementation. On changing the order lombok getter & setter are created first which are then used by mapstruct, so that why changin g order of `annotationProcessor` works !!

Comment: That would be flaky af if the order of dependencies would matter. In my case it does not help using Gradle and I'm glad it did not help. Are you using Maven?

Comment: Yes I am using Maven

Comment: I have found out that it is really the same with Gradle as well after reading the other answers and I had to forgot to re-arrange the `testAnnotationProcessors` as well. Seems to really be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, and the culprit was the use of

```
@Accessors(fluent=true)
```

on my Entity classes. Serves me right for using experimental Lombok features! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure if this problem still coming for anyone.
I have encountered the same problem and the issue is due to invalid mappings.
As in your case to map the packaging_id in the map struct interface you should mention like

```java
@Mapping(source = "packaging.field_name" target = "drinkPackaging")
```

here packaging is the field name of `Packaging` entity and `field_name` is whatever the field you want to assign which is declared in your packaging entity.
The naming conventions should match exactly means the field name in your entity should be the same as in your mapper interface source attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> For people who asking ****Why**** (not only looking for the code - [Jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69649688/15758781) answer was correct)

Lombok generates(actually modifies as tree node exploit to Tokenize stream for modifying the AST) constructors and methods at compile-time using a Java annotations processor and [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://research.google/pubs/pub37352/), MapStruct having almost the same mechanism (its way simpler cause of the fact it actually generates new nodes instead of node exploit) for generating concrete mapping implementation but it  uses constructors to create instances of target and source objects during mapping.  If it can't find constructor for the entity classes, it results in an ambiguous constructors in compilation time, they way to overcome this exception is to first let constructors being created before Mapstruct accessing them, which can be achieved by adding Lombok path before Mpastruct within  in [Maven Compiler](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) plugin (if its your build system, for Gradle same concept holds).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    ...
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      </path>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
    ...
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this pluging at the end of my plugin list and it solved the issue for me:
(I had this plugin but not at the end of list)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Steps:

1. Generate `Getters / Setters` for `Drink` and `DrinkDTO` classes(maybe without `Lombok`).
2. Build project with `Gradle` Task: `Build`
3. Start project!