# MapStruct mapper returns empty mapped object

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

I'm trying to use MapStruct to map convert between dto and entity objects, however the generated mapper implementation only returns **empty** mapped object.

**BeerMapperImpl**

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-11-05T07:42:21+0800",
    comments = "version: 1.3.0.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class BeerMapperImpl implements BeerMapper {

    @Override
    public BeerDto beerToBeerDto(Beer beer) {
        if ( beer == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        BeerDto beerDto = new BeerDto();

        return beerDto;
    }
}
```

Below are my codes.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>
                    org.projectlombok
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>
                -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
            </compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**BeerMapper.java**

```
@Mapper(uses = {DateMapper.class})
public interface BeerMapper {
    BeerDto beerToBeerDto(Beer beer);
    Beer beerDtoToBeer(Beer dto);
}
```

Anyone can help to advise what might go wrong in my codes? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue after downgrading spring boot starter from 2.3.5.RELEASE to 2.1.5.RELEASE.

Answer (score 40):

I have found the solution without having to downgrade spring boot. The problem was that I was using `lombok` to generate getters and setters, on the other side `mapstruct` looks for getters and setters in your objects to populate them, but in this case it couldn't find them simply because during the compilation `mapstruct` was running before `lombok` could generate them.

The solution is simply to write the configuration of `lombok` before the configuration of `mapstruct` in your pom.xml file to execute lombok in first place. Make sure to run `clean compile` to delete old files.

Working configuration of maven-compiler-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <!--Project Lombok compile preprocessor-->
      <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      </path>
      <!--Maps Struct compile preprocessor-->
      <path>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct-ver}</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Perfect!

A detail that is not well described when combining the two technologies.

Solved my problem!

Comment: Can you please add solution for gradle

Comment: Perfect Answer!

Comment: well explained :)

Comment: Reordering annotation processors works for Gradle as well. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This answer should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I removed annotation Processor Paths tag and declared bot lombok and mapstruct as dependency.

link with similar issue:
[MapStruct and Lombok not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem where all the values in the object created by the mapstruct mapping had null values when the original object was populated.  When I checked the generated mapper in target the generated implementation did not contain an actual mapping.  I found that this was easily fixed when I made a small change to the Mapper in my project and saved it.  The mapper in target was re-generated with the mapping in place.  I'm not sure why the mapper was generated incorrectly but this was a qick fix that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To the dto I added a @AllArgsConstructor, after removing it - works fine. Stupid, but works. The order of dependencies and paths was good, and spring boot version was older then proposed to downgrade

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As official documentation [suggest](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#lombok), newer versions of lombok require an aditional anotation processor dependency so you would need to add a new annotation processor like so (maven)

```
<path>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
  <version>***</version>
</path>
```

make sure you add the latest version compatible with your gradle build

for gradle users it will be something like this

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding'
```

this way it will work with no problem in new versions of spring