# My mapperImpl by mapstruct is not generating getters and setters

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, mapstruct

i would like to know why my mapperImpl generated by mapstruct isnt being generated with getters and setters.

I think that because of this, when i go make a GET request on postman it returns all null what shouldnt be returning null.

Im using maven, java 8 and spring-boot

**pom.xml:**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.celulaweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>crud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crud</name>
    <description>Crud Estudo CelulaWeb</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml</outputChangeLogFile>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/crud</url>
                    <username>root</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Mapper:**

```java
package com.celulaweb.crud.service.mappers;

import com.celulaweb.crud.domain.Cidade;
import com.celulaweb.crud.service.DTO.CidadeDTO;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CidadeMapper {

    CidadeDTO cidadeParaDTO(Cidade cidade);
    List<CidadeDTO> cidadeParaDTO(List<Cidade> cidade);
    Cidade cidadeDTOParaCidade(CidadeDTO cidadeDTO);

}
```

**EntittyDTO:**

```java
package com.celulaweb.crud.service.DTO;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
public class CidadeDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private Integer qtdHabitantes;
    private String estado;

}
```

**Entity:**

```java
package com.celulaweb.crud.domain;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cidade")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cidade {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String nome;

    private Integer qtdHabitantes;

    @NotNull
    private String estado;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) { return false; }
        if (obj == this) { return true; }
        if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Cidade rhs = (Cidade) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder()
                .appendSuper(super.equals(obj))
                .append(id, rhs.id)
                .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder().append(id).toHashCode();
    }
}
```

**mapperImpl:**

```java
package com.celulaweb.crud.service.mappers;

import com.celulaweb.crud.domain.Cidade;
import com.celulaweb.crud.service.DTO.CidadeDTO;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2022-01-20T13:49:14-0300",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.13 (Ubuntu)"
)
@Component
public class CidadeMapperImpl implements CidadeMapper {

    @Override
    public CidadeDTO cidadeParaDTO(Cidade cidade) {
        if ( cidade == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CidadeDTO cidadeDTO = new CidadeDTO();

        return cidadeDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CidadeDTO> cidadeParaDTO(List<Cidade> cidade) {
        if ( cidade == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<CidadeDTO> list = new ArrayList<CidadeDTO>( cidade.size() );
        for ( Cidade cidade1 : cidade ) {
            list.add( cidadeParaDTO( cidade1 ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Cidade cidadeDTOParaCidade(CidadeDTO cidadeDTO) {
        if ( cidadeDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Cidade cidade = new Cidade();

        return cidade;
    }
}
```

If someone know how to solve, please help. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use mapstruct together with lombok you have to include lombok-mapstruct-binding in your pom.xml

have a look at "Can I use MapStruct together with Project Lombok?" under https://mapstruct.org/faq/

like this:

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </path> 
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </path>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Comment: remember the include order makes sense, mapstruct should include after lombok. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67046205/10951158