# Mapstruct and Lombok unexpected result with Spring Boot 2.4 and above Is there any workaround or issues with this version?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, lombok, mapstruct, java-15

I'm using the latest versions of Spring boot above 2.2.5 and Java 15, lombok, Mapstruct for mapping some pojos.

When using ***version 2.2.5 of spring boot*** I'm getting the expected result :

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-01-02T21:59:24+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 15.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class ProduitMapperImpl implements ProduitMapper {

    @Override
    public ProduitDtoResponse produitToProduitDtoResponse(Produit produit) {
        if ( produit == null ) {
            return null;
        }

    ProduitDtoResponseBuilder produitDtoResponse = ProduitDtoResponse.builder();

    produitDtoResponse.id( produit.getId() );
    produitDtoResponse.nom( produit.getNom() );
    produitDtoResponse.prix( produit.getPrix() );

    return produitDtoResponse.build();
}

@Override
public Produit produitToProduitDtoResponse(ProduitDtoResponse produitDto) {
    if ( produitDto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    ProduitBuilder produit = Produit.builder();

    produit.id( produitDto.getId() );
    produit.nom( produitDto.getNom() );
    produit.prix( produitDto.getPrix() );

    return produit.build();
    }
}
```

But when using *Version 2.4 and above*, there's *no builder*, instead I have the *java new keyword and not the other fields*, I'm getting :

Here's the maven pom conf that's not working : [BOM](https://github.com/NaoufalHightech/ecommerce-microservice-bom/blob/master/pom.xml)

```
@Generated(
value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
date = "2021-01-02T22:05:16+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 15.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)"
)

@Component
public class ProduitMapperImpl implements ProduitMapper {

    @Override
    public ProduitDtoResponse produitToProduitDtoResponse(Produit produit) {
        if ( produit == null ) {
            return null;
        }
    ProduitDtoResponse produitDtoResponse = new ProduitDtoResponse();

    return produitDtoResponse;
}

@Override
public Produit produitToProduitDtoResponse(ProduitDtoResponse produitDto) {
    if ( produitDto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    Produit produit = new Produit();

    return produit;
}
}
```

The only thing I change is Spring Boot version and it work as expected, is there any workaround or issues with *version 2.4 and above* of Spring Boot, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MapStruct and Lombok not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together)

Comment: @Filip No, the `annotationProcessorPaths` are not missing, the problem is that `lombok-mapstruct-binding` is needed for Lombok 1.18.16 and later.

Comment: I know what the problem is. Did you check the edits of the answer? It says explicitly that you need to add `lombok-mapstruct-binding` from Lombok 1.18.16

Comment: @Filip Ah, no, I just saw that it was talking about Lombok 1.16.14 and missing Lombok from the annotation processors. I see the later edit now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that because of this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<version>${lombok.version}</version>
```

you are getting the Lombok version from the parent pom of your parent pom, `spring-boot-starter-parent` (your grandparent pom?), and thus with Spring Boot 2.4.0 you are picking up a newer version of Lombok.

Starting with Lombok 1.18.16, you need to add another dependency. See this answer in the [MapStruct FAQ](https://mapstruct.org/faq/#can-i-use-mapstruct-together-with-project-lombok):

> If you are using Lombok 1.18.16 or newer you also need to add [lombok-mapstruct-binding](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-mapstruct-binding) in order to make Lombok and MapStruct work together.

They have a [sample project](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-lombok) to demonstrate how to use them together. Here are the relevant parts of the sample `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <!-- . . . -->
    <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
</properties>

<!-- . . . -->

        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <!-- . . . -->
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
```