# java: No implementation was created for ProductMapper due to having a problem in the erroneous element java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, mapstruct

I'm trying to create very simple JUnit test into Spring Cloud project:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ProductMapper.class })
public class TestingWebApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper(config = BaseMapperConfig.class)
public interface ProductMapper {

    ProductDTO toDTO(Product product);

    ProductFullDTO toFullDTO(Product product);

    Product map(ProductFullDTO productDTO);

    ProductFilter toFilter(ProductFilterDTO dto);
}
```

I get this error when I try to run the test into the latest Intelij.

> java: No implementation was created for ProductMapper due to having a
> problem in the erroneous element java.util.ArrayList. Hint: this often
> means that some other annotation processor was supposed to process the
> erroneous element. You can also enable MapStruct verbose mode by
> setting -Amapstruct.verbose=true as a compilation argument.

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What is the output when you set `-Amapstruct.verbose=true`? Are you using Lombok by any chance?

Comment: I haven't use this debug option so far. Yes I use Lombook

Comment: Then I suggest having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together/47684351

Answer (score 24):

Try to reorder your annotation processor factory path, move lombok to the top.

Comment: In this case previous error returns: "java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable log"

Comment: Perfect tip. Thanx.

order in my annotation processor : 
1- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30
2- org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0
3- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final

Answer (score 1):

Use the generated implementation of the mapper within the Spring test configuration:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ProductMapperImpl.class })
```

Also remember that the mapper itself should be bound to the Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly related to MapStruct itself, but maybe it will save some devs a few minutes / hours when searching for the problem.

I had a similar problem in a project, where I was supposed to add new API version and mark old one as deprecated.

When I tried compiling with maven, I got errors

```
[ERROR] /src/main/java/com/example/MapStructMapperClass.java: No implementation was created for MapStructMapperClass.java due to having a problem in the erroneous element java.util.ArrayList. Hint: this often means that some other annotation processor was supposed to process the erroneous element. You can also enable MapStruct verbose mode by setting -Amapstruct.verbose=true as a compilation argument.
```

The project uses Lombok, so I checked annotation processor configs. Looked fine and worked properly on a simple, ad hoc created project.
Tried bumping MapStruct and Lpmbok versions. Still the same problem.

Then, I noticed a few lines in the log:

```
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :
[INFO] ------------------------------
[WARNING] /src/main/java/com/example/MyRestController.java: com.example.MyOldService in MyRestController has been deprecated
[INFO] 1 warning
[INFO] ----------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] ----------------------
[ERROR] warnings found and -Werror specified
```

And the config in maven pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
  <configuration>
</plugin>
```

As [Javac JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) states:

```
-Werror
    Terminate compilation if warnings occur.
```

So, my problem was that I used @Deprecated annotation and someone turned treating compilation warnings as errors on. Due to the project using MapStruct and having pleeeeenty of mappers with the same compilation error, I focused on solving the problem with the annotations processors, completely ignoring those "insignificant" warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case the root cause was related to my **multi-module architecture**.

The top-level mapper has used one child mapper of **module A** which used itself a child mapper of **module B**.

Gradle **module A** has dependency implementation of **module B**

> implementation("module-b")

This means the **application module** has **no access** to classes of **transitive dependency B through module A** which makes MapStruct fail with this error:

> No implementation was created for **MapperOfApplication** due to having a problem
> in the erroneous element **EntityOfModuleB**. Hint: this often
> means that some other annotation processor was supposed to process the
> erroneous element. You can also enable MapStruct verbose mode by
> setting -Amapstruct.verbose=true as a compilation argument.

The odd thing is, mapper for **EntityOfModuleB** is not even used, as **EntityOfModuleADto** has no reference to **EntityOfModuleBDto** and in my opinion this error should not occur in my case. (**MapStruct bug?**)

However, as a **solution** I had to additionally **include** dependency `implementation("module-b")` into my **application module**