# Mapstruct seems not recognize Lombok's @SuperBuilder

Tags: java, lombok, builder, mapstruct

I have two domain classes like these.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    private String name;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student extends User {
    private int grade;
}
```

And I have also two Dto classes like these.

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class UserDto {
    private final String name;
}
```

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class StudentDto extends UserDto {
    private final int grade;
}
```

So I made a mapper class StudentMapper which extends GenericMapper.

```
public interface GenericMapper<D, E> {
    D toDto(E e);
    E toEntity(D d);
}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface StudentMapper extends GenericMapper<StudentDto, Student> {
}
```

But I got an error while compiling Mapper.

"StudentDto does not have an accessible constructor."

What's wrong with those codes?

I want StudentDto to be unmodifiable.
What will be the best way to get there with lombok and mapstruct?

You can get the source codes from here.
https://github.com/jangdaewon/sandbox.lombokmapstruct

Comment: Could you try changing the order of your `<annotationProcessorPaths>` such that Lombok is the last entry?

Comment: @JanRieke Error message has gone after change the order of `<annotationProcessorPaths>`. Thanks.

Comment: Great. I added this as an answer (with a bit of explanation). It would be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit counter-intuitive, but Lombok has to be put *after* mapstruct in the list of annotation processors. Mapstruct detects Lombok and waits until Lombok has done its job completely (Lombok may need several annotation processing rounds).

So simply change the order of your processors in the `<configuration>` of `maven-compiler-plugin` in your `pom.xml` like this:

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </path>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </path>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Comment: I have nothing to say but surprise, is there any references? it works well !
if mapstruct require lombok, shoudn't the lombok be defined first?
Is this the `counter-intuitive`you mentioned?

Comment: This conflicts with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together