# Mapstruct 1.5.x.Final and Lombok >= 1.18.20 with Gradle not working

Tags: lombok, dropwizard, mapstruct

In my current project I'm always getting compilation errors like `Unknown property "xxx" in result type "yyy". Did you mean "zzz"`? I already walked through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together), checked the Mapstruct [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#lombok), compared my code with [this example](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/main/mapstruct-lombok/build.gradle) and read lots of other posts, which all did not help.

Using the following entries in the `build.gradle`

```
project.ext {
  sdaseVersion = '2.53.1'
  lombokVersion = '1.18.24'
  mapStructVersion = '1.4.2.Final'
  lombokMapStructBindingVersion = '0.2.0'
}

dependencies {
  …

  implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapStructVersion}"
  compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"

  annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
  annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapStructVersion}"
  annotationProcessor  "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:${lombokMapStructBindingVersion}"
}
```

... my code compiles and runs without any issues (note it's `1.4.2.Final` here). Once I increase the version to `1.5.2.Final` I'm getting the erros as written above. I tried also to exchange the order of annotation processors, reloaded my project and invalidated my cache without success.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I just tried the same with my project (lifting mapstruct to 1.5.2.Final), and that still compiles fine. Could you give some details on the code that causes the errors?

Comment: Meanwhile I saw that the issue could be related to this one documented at github: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2743. It seems like Mapstruct 1.5.2 handles the annotation `ignoreUnmappedSourceProperties` somewhat differently. I'd like to keep using `ReportingPolicy.ERROR`, because I think it's beneficial and so I have to define the source fields to ignore.