# MapStruct mapper error: Unknown property "propertyName" in result type Dto. Did you mean "null"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

```
// Driver model
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Driver {
    private String driverName;
    private String licenseNumber;
}

// Car model
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Car {
    private String make;
    private List<Driver> drivers;
    private CarType type;
}

// Car DTO
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CarDto {
    private String make;
    private Integer totalDrivers;
    private String type;
}

@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "totalDrivers", expression = "java(mapDrivers(car.getDrivers()))")
    CarDto mapCarDto(Car car);

    default Integer mapDrivers(List<Driver> totalDrivers) {
        return totalDrivers.size();
    }

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    @Mapping(target = "drivers", ignore = true)
    Car mapDtoToCar(CarDto carDto);
}
```

**When I RUN this project those errors are reported:**

```
..\CarMapper.java
java: Unknown property "totalDrivers" in result type CarDto. Did you mean "null"?
java: Unknown property "drivers" in result type Car. Did you mean "null"?
```

How can I get solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be related to Lombok.

Take a look at:

- Official documentation: [Can I use MapStruct together with Project Lombok?](https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Can-I-use-MapStruct-together-with-Project-Lombok)

  project example: [github/mapstruct-examples/mapstruct-lombok/](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/main/mapstruct-lombok)
- Guide step-by-step: [Using Mapstruct With Project Lombok](https://springframework.guru/using-mapstruct-with-project-lombok/)
- StackOverflow question: [MapStruct and Lombok not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together)

Comment: No, same massage returned, but in Initcap "Unknown property "Drivers" in result type Car. Did you mean "null"?"

Comment: @SubarataTalukder ok, maybe the problem is relative to using lombok. I updated the answer with a guide step by step.

Comment: Thanks a loot @Paul Marcelin Bejan. In my code everything was correct rather than "Maven Annotation Processing Configuration". I mistook to add "lombok" and "lombok-mapstruct-binding". I followed the "Guide step-by-step: Using Mapstruct With Project Lombok".  Now everything is ok. Thanks again.

Comment: @SubarataTalukder Just for my curiosity, it’s working with the lowercase or with the Initcap?

Comment: It’s working with the lowercase. Like my code above.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the `annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:${lombokMapstructBindingVersion}"` to the build.gradle and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking to fix a more simpler problem could just add some getters and setters in a DTO.

In my case this helped.

**You should pay attention to the Capital letters, I find it bit counter intuitive but, anyway some convention has to be there for the mapping**

My DTO

```
public class SalesOrderDTO {

    private Integer SOID;
    private LocalDate SOOrderDate;

    private String CustomerName;
    private String CustomerID;

    private LocalDate SODueDate;

    private Boolean SOIsClosed;

    private LocalDateTime SOLastModified;


    public Integer getSOID() {
        return SOID;
    }

    public void setSOID(Integer SOID) {
        this.SOID = SOID;
    }

    public LocalDate getSOOrderDate() {
        return SOOrderDate;
    }

    public void setSOOrderDate(LocalDate SOOrderDate) {
        this.SOOrderDate = SOOrderDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getSODueDate() {
        return SODueDate;
    }

    public void setSODueDate(LocalDate SODueDate) {
        this.SODueDate = SODueDate;
    }

    public Boolean getSOIsClosed() {
        return SOIsClosed;
    }

    public void setSOIsClosed(Boolean SOIsClosed) {
        this.SOIsClosed = SOIsClosed;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getSOLastModified() {
        return SOLastModified;
    }

    public void setSOLastModified(LocalDateTime SOLastModified) {
        this.SOLastModified = SOLastModified;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return CustomerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        CustomerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getCustomerID() {
        return CustomerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(String customerID) {
        CustomerID = customerID;
    }
}
```

My Mapper

```
@Mapper(
        componentModel = "spring",
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR
)
public interface SalesOrderMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "customer.fullName", target = "customerName")
    @Mapping(source = "customer.NCCustomerID", target = "customerID")
    SalesOrderDTO toDto(SalesOrder salesOrder);
}
```