# MapStruct in Dropwizard doesn't build when application builds initially for first time

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard, mapstruct

I am facing issues to make `mapstruct` library work with dropwizard. My mapping interface and binding looks like below:

```
@Mapper (componentModel = "jsr330", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, builder = @Builder (disableBuilder = true))
public interface StudentMapper {
    StudentMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(StudentMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "firstname")
    StudentEntity toStudentEntity(StudentDto student);
}
```

Binding:

```
bind(StudentMapper.class).toInstance(StudentMapper.INSTANCE);
```

When I build my application like this for first time then following error comes. It's not the error of incorrect source and target field names as they start working as I explained below.

```
error: No property named "name" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "null"?
    StudentEntity toStudentEntity(StudentDto student);
```

Now, if I comment the mapping line and build then application build successfullly but no mapping works

```
@Mapper (componentModel = "jsr330", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, builder = @Builder (disableBuilder = true))
public interface StudentMapper {
    StudentMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(StudentMapper.class);

    // @Mapping(target = "name", source = "firstname")
    StudentEntity toStudentEntity(StudentDto student);
}
```

When application build successfully for one time and if now I uncomment the mapping line and run the code it works perfectly and all the mappings work.
Obviously, I cannot do this in production environment and can do in local only.

How do I fix this issue so that it works in one go?

EDIT: Student entity looks like:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
class StudentEntity {
  private String name;
}
```

Comment: How does the `StudentEntity` look like?

Comment: Do you use Lombok?

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk Yes, I am using lombok.

Comment: @Filip Have updated the StudentEntity in question.

Comment: I think it can be related to Lombok, take a look at this answer on how to configure MapStruct with Lombok: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240201/13115701