# MapStrut maping not working with class using lombok

Tags: spring, mapping, lombok, mapstruct

I'm modifying the mapping on existing software. It uses MapStruct (1.2.0), and Lombok (1.16.18)

Before modification, I have this class:

```
public class ReservationCreateRSRDTO {
    @JsonProperty("reservation_id")
    private String reservationId;
}
```

I need to change it to

```
@Data
@GenerateCoverage
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ReservationCreateRSRDTO {
    @JsonProperty("delivery_slot_reservation")
    private DeliverySlotReservation deliverySlotReservation;
}

@Data
@GenerateCoverage
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class DeliverySlotReservation {
    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty("identifier")
    @Size(min = 13, max = 13)
    private String identifier;
    
}
```

which is mapped by

```
@Mapper
public interface ReservationControllerMapper {
    ReservationCreateRSRDTO toReservationCreateRSRDTO(ReservationCreateODTO reservationCreateODTO);
}
```

The source object:

```
@Data
@GenerateCoverage
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ReservationCreateODTO {

    private String reservationId;
}
```

I modified the mapping to

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "reservationId", target = "deliverySlotReservation.identifier"),
})
ReservationCreateRSRDTO toReservationCreateRSRDTO(ReservationCreateODTO reservationCreateODTO);
```

But when accessing attribute `deliverySlotReservation` from `ReservationCreateRSRDTO` after the mapping, it returns null.

I'm trying to debug in eclipse, into generated classes:

```
@Override
public ReservationCreateRSRDTO toReservationCreateRSRDTO(ReservationCreateODTO reservationCreateODTO) {
    if ( reservationCreateODTO == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    ReservationCreateRSRDTO reservationCreateRSRDTO = new ReservationCreateRSRDTO();
    reservationCreateRSRDTO.setDeliverySlotReservation( 
        reservationCreateODTOToDeliverySlotReservation( reservationCreateODTO ) );
    return reservationCreateRSRDTO;
}

protected DeliverySlotReservation reservationCreateODTOToDeliverySlotReservation(ReservationCreateODTO reservationCreateODTO) {
    if ( reservationCreateODTO == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    DeliverySlotReservation deliverySlotReservation = new DeliverySlotReservation();
    deliverySlotReservation.setIdentifier( reservationCreateODTO.getReservationId() );
    return deliverySlotReservation;
}
```

I call toReservationCreateRSRDTO with a not null `ReservationCreateODTO` with not null identifier
but debugger is not stepping into `reservationCreateODTOToDeliverySlotReservation()`.

No exception es thrown, but `toReservationCreateRSRDTO()` returns an `ReservationCreateRSRDTO` object with null 'deliverySlotReservation'

**Edit**

I found a workaround for it with a custom mapping:

```
@Mapping(source = "reservationId", target = "deliverySlotReservation", qualifiedByName = "toDeliverySlotReservation")
    ReservationCreateRSRDTO toReservationCreateRSRDTO(ReservationCreateODTO reservationCreateODTO);

    @Named("toOrder")
    public static DeliverySlotReservation toDeliverySlotReservation(String identifier) {
        return new DeliverySlotReservation(identifier);
    }
```

but still don´t know why it does not work with the normal mapping

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240201/13115701