# Mapstruct - abstract target class fields mapping

Tags: java, mapstruct

Source classes:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private final String name; // with getter
}
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private final int numOfDoors; // with getter
}
public class Motorbike extends Vehicle {
    private final boolean allowedForMinor; // with getter
}
```

Target classes:

```
public abstract class VehicleDto {
    private final String name;
    public VehicleDto(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
public class CarDto extends VehicleDto {
    private final int numOfDoors;
    public CarDto(String name, int numOfDoors) {
        super(name);
        this.numOfDoors = numOfDoors;
    }
}
public class MotorbikeDto extends VehicleDto {
    private final boolean allowedForMinor;
    public MotorbikeDto(String name, boolean allowedForMinor) {
        super(name);
        this.allowedForMinor = allowedForMinor;
    }
}
```

Mapper config:

```
@Mapper(subclassExhaustiveStrategy = SubclassExhaustiveStrategy.RUNTIME_EXCEPTION)
public interface VehicleMapper {
    @SubclassMapping(target = CarDto.class, source = Car.class)
    @SubclassMapping(target = MotorbikeDto.class, source = Motorbike.class)
    VehicleDto mapToDto(Vehicle vehicle);
}
```

Everything works fine so far, the mapper class is generated and mapping correctly all the fields.
The problem occurs when I'm trying to add anything related to `name` field in VehicleDto, for example:

```
@Mapper(subclassExhaustiveStrategy = SubclassExhaustiveStrategy.RUNTIME_EXCEPTION)
public interface VehicleMapper {
    @SubclassMapping(target = CarDto.class, source = Car.class)
    @SubclassMapping(target = MotorbikeDto.class, source = Motorbike.class)
    @Mapping(target = "name", constant = "noname") // <-------- added this one --------
    VehicleDto mapToDto(Vehicle vehicle);
}
```

In this case I'm getting a compilation error:

> Unknown property "name" in result type VehicleDto. Did you mean
> "null"?

How can Mapstruct recognize the field `name` by default, and not with custom config? Is there a clean Mapstruct way to fix this, preferably without any changes to the source/target classes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MapStruct mapper error: Unknown property "propertyName" in result type Dto. Did you mean "null"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240057/mapstruct-mapper-error-unknown-property-propertyname-in-result-type-dto-did)

Comment: No, that's not my case. I don't have Lombok in my project.

Comment: This should work out of the box. Can you please raise an issue in the MapStruct project?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out. I need to use `@MapperConfig`:

```
@MapperConfig
public interface VehicleMapperConfig {
    @Mapping(target = "name", constant = "noname")
    void mapVehicleToDto(Vehicle vehicle, @MappingTarget VehicleDto target);
}

@Mapper(config = VehicleMapperConfig.class, subclassExhaustiveStrategy = RUNTIME_EXCEPTION)
public interface VehicleMapper {
    @InheritConfiguration(name = "mapVehicleToDto")
    @SubclassMapping(target = CarDto.class, source = Car.class)
    @SubclassMapping(target = MotorbikeDto.class, source = Motorbike.class)
    VehicleDto mapToDto(Vehicle vehicle);
}
```

With this solution the superclass field `name` is mapped properly.