# Mapstruct not working properly with Java 17 records

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

I'm moving some code from Java 11 to Java 17 and I'm having an issue using Mapstruct to convert a class to a record (that was previously a class).

Let's say I have this record

```java
public record SomeRecord(String a, String b, String c) {}
```

And I have this other class using Lombok annotations:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SomeClass{
  private String x;
  private String y;
  private String z;
}
```

Later in my mapping I have a function to convert from `SomeClass` to `SomeRecord`

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface Mapper {

  @Mapping(target = "c", source = "someClass.z", qualifiedByName = "mapperFunction")
  SomeRecord toSomeRecord(SomeClass someClass);

  @Named("mapperFunction")
  static String someTransformation(String s) {
    //implementation not relevant
  }
}
```

And I'm getting two compiling errors:

- First it says that "Unknown property 'c' in result type SomeRecord. Did you mean 'null'?"
- Secondly it states that there's no "accessible parameterless constructor for `SomeRecord`".

I did research and found that mapstruct is supporting java records so it's not clear for me why these errors are occurring.

I'm using:

- mapstruct 1.5.2.Final (latest as of publication date)
- lombok 1.18.22
- openjdk 17.0.4

Note: Maybe it is evident that I should also move `SomeClass` to a record, but for now please assume this is not possible.

**Edit:** I'm also using Mapstruct + lombok binding and these errors are happening despite.

Comment: It looks like MapStruct thinks it's dealing with a regular Java bean (with a no-args constructor, getters and setters). Did you regenerate the MapStruct mappers, or are you compiling the code with an old mapper that was originally built when `SomeClass` was still a regular class?

Comment: I believe that the problem is the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together and the `lombok-mapstruct-binding` dependency is missing

Comment: This mapstruct lombok binding dependency was already added. Version is 0.2.0, which is why I don't think that doesn't resolve the issue