# Maven annotation processor (of MapStruct) raise compilation failure

Tags: mapstruct, annotation-processing, maven-compiler-plugin

I am trying to work with MapStruct, according to the documentation [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_apache_maven). It requires defining `AnnotationProcessor` as part of the compiler plugin. when using the annotation processor the code does not compile, failing on some unrelated compilation errors. (cannot find symbol;cannot infer type arguments for...).

I was able to narrow down the problem to simple test case ([github](https://github.com/the-shultz/problem-maven-annotation-processor)):

consider this class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Result<D, E> {
    private D data;
    private E error;
}
```

...and this generic method that uses the class `Result`:

```
    public static <D, E> Result<D, E> createResult(D data, Class<E> type) {
        Result<D, E> res = new Result<>();
        res.setData(data);
        return res;
    }
```

I am using it like that:

```
Result<String, String> test = createResult("Test", String.class);
```

code works and **compiles successfully**, using this maven compiler plugin definition:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.10.1</version>
     <configuration>
         <source>11</source>
         <target>11</target>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

... but fails when adding the `annotationProcessorPaths` of `MapStruct`, with error `cannot find symbol` on the line `res.setData(data);`

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I tried a similar generic method with generic `List`, but it works ok from some reason in this example:

```
    public static <T> List<T> createListWithItem(T item) {
        List<T> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.add(item);
        return res;
    }
    
    ....
    
    List<String> list = createListWithItem("BANANA");
```

(You can clone the repo and simply add\remove the `annotationProcessorPaths` elements to toggle the problem)

I am not sure if it even related to `MapStruct`, or simply something with the mention and usage of any annotationProcessor.

my questions:

1. what's the problem that only adding the annotation processor makes the code not compile ?
2. is it really realted to MapStruct or something in the compiler plugin ?
   any idea ?
3. what's the difference between the `Result` example and the `List` example ?

Comment: The problem is the use of Lombok. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together

Comment: Indeed this is a duplicate. For some reason, I missed the original question with the correct answer. The problem was in the order of applying the annotation processors, as described in the attached question