# variable not initialized in the default constructor Lombok Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations, lombok

There is an issue **variable usersRepository not initialized in the default constructor** called in this class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UsersDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = usersRepository.findByEmail(username);

        if(user.isEmpty())
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");

        return new UsersDetails(user.get());
    }
}
```

Also I have problems with all Lombok annotations during compilation my program. I think there is a problem with some versions. **I have already installed and updated lombok plugin, but the problem still hasn't solved**

There is my **pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CharityOrganizationSpringApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CharityOrganizationSpringApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <modelmapper.version>3.0.0</modelmapper.version>
        <java-jwt.version>4.4.0</java-jwt.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.3.final</mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${java-jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You need to configure the [Lombok compiler plugin](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven) in that POM file too

Comment: I have lombok dependency and plugin in pom.xml,  but it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MapStruct and Lombok not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together)

Comment: where are you getting the "issue"?

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this as well. I had to add the Maven artifact lombok-mapstruct-binding to the maven-compiler-plugin like so:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This solved the issue for me. I read in the [changelog of lombok](https://projectlombok.org/changelog) I should have done this ever since version v1.18.16 (January 28th, 2021). I was just lucky I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your wording is slightly off here but when you say "variable usersRepository not initialized in the default constructor", this implies you're creating an instance of UsersDetailsService by calling an empty constructor (no arguments).

If this is the case then usersRepository will be null since it is only initialized in the constructor created from @RequiredArgsConstructor.

If you are expecting the constructor created from @RequiredArgsConstructor to be called automatically through dependency injection and usersRepository is still null then check that you are creating a UsersRepository bean that can be injected. Annotating UsersRepository with @Repository will accomplish this if you are using a JPA repository.

Also, if you are using a JPA repository then ensure you have the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in your app config, that points to the base package of your repositories.

Comment: I have added EnableJpaRepositories to my config file, and checked there is Repository in UserRepository class, but it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

add those lines into build.gradle file. additionally Java 21 and lombok are compatible.

```
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
```